# how to enable websocket on JBoss 4

Tags: java, jboss, websocket

I need to run java websockets on JBoss 4.2.3
is this doable, because I have searched a lot on the internet and found that JBoss 6 and up support web socket.
is this true?

if it is applicable, can you point me to a tutorial on how to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Even JBoss 6 doesn't support websockets out of box. But you can use Atmosphere library to get asynchronous communication on JBoss 6. Check out this link which has list of supported servers.

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Supported-WebServers-and-Browsers

Better, upgrade your server version. It's too old.